# Papa Parse: Save JSON Output Locally

Tags: javascript, json, papaparse

I have the following code:

```
Papa.parse("/drivencarstock.csv", {
  download: true,
  header: true,
    step: function(row) {
        console.log("Row:", row.data);
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

As you can see I am parsing the 'drivencarstock.csv' file and it outputs into my console perfectly however now I am just wondering how I can output this as a json file on my server?

I can't see how this might be done?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step would be to actually collect the parsed data in a variable, such as an array. Then in the `step` you'd add the row.data to this array. Once `complete` you could `POST` the data using AJAX.

For example:

```
//  create the array to hold the data
var myRows = [];

Papa.parse("/drivencarstock.csv", {
  download: true,
  header: true,
    step: function(row) {
        //  push the row data into the array
        myRows.push(row.data);
    },
    complete: function() {
        //  upload using jQuery's AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url: '/path/on/your/server',
          method: 'post',
          data: myRows,
          success: function(response) {
            console.log('upload complete', response);
          },
          error: function() {
            console.error('an error occurred');
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Now, there are a couple of optimisations that could be made, such as posting the array every time it contains a fair amount of data and properly responding to the AJAX success/error callbacks, but this should get you going.